# How pyspark does reduce by key to list of lists

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

my program needs to do reduce by key to list of list. The column codelist could be huge, so I need to do reduce based on column code_deDup which is already de-duplicated sequence, now I need count based on sequence list again. I could just use def kvListSum to do work, but it's not elegant, not python/pyspark spirit.

This question is NOT same as [PySpark reduceByKey aggregation after collect_list on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452209/pyspark-reducebykey-aggregation-after-collect-list-on-a-column), as that was like to get column code_deDup, this is to get count of code_Dedup list, which is further step. Thank you.

my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from collections import Counter
def code_deDup(codelist):
    temp_list = []
    for item in codelist:   
        if len(temp_list) > 0:
            if temp_list[-1][0] != item:
                temp_list.append([item,1])
            else:
                temp_list[-1][1] += 1
        else:
            temp_list.append([item,1])
    return temp_list

def kvListSum(mylist):
    #cnt=Counter()
    #for key,value in mylist:
    #    cnt[key] += value
    #return cnt
    #return mylist[0]
    temp_list = []
    for item in mylist:
        if len(temp_list) > 0:
            boolfound = False
            for temp in temp_list:
                if item[0] == temp[0]:
                    temp[1] += item[1]
                    boolfound = True
                    break
            if boolfound == False:
                temp_list.append(item)    
        else:
            temp_list.append(item)
    return temp_list

schema = ArrayType(StructType([    StructField("char", StringType(), False),    StructField("count", IntegerType(), False)]))
code_deDup_udf = udf(code_deDup, schema)
udf2 = udf(kvListSum)
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local")
conf = conf.setAppName("test")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
rdd = sc.parallelize([('20171127',[ 'AR','AR','CR','CR','BR','BR','AR','AR','CR','CR'   ]),\
                      ('20171128',[ 'CR','CR','BR','BR','AR','AR','CR','CR','BR','BR'   ])]) 
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, ["date", "codelist"])
df = df.withColumn('code_deDup', code_deDup_udf('codelist')).withColumn('codeSum', udf2('code_deDup'))
#df.printSchema()
df.show(2,False)
```

the output is:

+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|date    |codelist                                |code_deDup                              |
+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|20171127|[AR, AR, CR, CR, BR, BR, AR, AR, CR, CR]|[[AR,2], [CR,2], [BR,2], [AR,2], [CR,2]]|
|20171128|[CR, CR, BR, BR, AR, AR, CR, CR, BR, BR]|[[CR,2], [BR,2], [AR,2], [CR,2], [BR,2]]|
+--------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+

I want a new column further aggregated by 'code_deDup':

```
[[AR,2], [CR,2], [BR,2], [AR,2], [CR,2]] --->  [AR, 4],[CR,4],[BR,2]
[[CR,2], [BR,2], [AR,2], [CR,2], [BR,2]] --->  [CR, 4],[BR,4],[AR,2]
```

I could just use def kvListSum to do work, but it's not elegant, so ask you idea.

Comment: What is your input, what is your expected Output? What part isn't working?

Comment: how is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452209/pyspark-reducebykey-aggregation-after-collect-list-on-a-column/ ?

Comment: @mtoto I was writing the same answer but I was hesitating between using Counter or a regular iteration

Comment: the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452209/pyspark-reducebykey-aggregation-after-collect-list-on-a-column which is also asked by me, it's not same question. This question can be treated as further question to previous one. this one is to do aggregation again from list of lists.